# Async chunked JS file upload to Flask backend on Debian

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, upload, xmlhttprequest

I want to implement a chunked file upload for `.tar` files without libs (with the exception of Flask).
This code works only if i upload in sync `xhr.open(async=false)` mode (JavaScript) but if i change it to run in async mode i can't extract the uploaded `.tar` with the error `tar: Skipping to next header`.

I think the problem is in the backend but i also post my shortened `upload.js` here.

upload.js

```js
    async uploadFile(url, file, onload, onerror) {
        const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
        const fileSize = file.size;
        const fileName = file.name;
        const totalChunks = Math.ceil(fileSize / CHUNK_SIZE);
        const chunks = [];
        var stop = false;


        for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
            const start = i * CHUNK_SIZE;
            const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize);  // last chunk use fileSize
            const chunk = file.slice(start, end);
            chunks.push(chunk);
        }

        // ...
        // xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        // ...
        // xhr.send(chunk)
```

api.py

```py
@api.route('/upload/g', methods=['POST'])
def upload_g():
    # load own headers
    total_chunks = int(request.headers['Total-Chunks']) if request.headers.get('Total-Chunks') else None
    chunk_index = int(request.headers['Chunk-Index']) if request.headers.get('Chunk-Index') else None
    orig_file_name = request.headers.get('File-Name', False)
    unique_upload_id = request.headers.get('Unique-Upload-Id', False)

    # check if required headers are set
    if not all((total_chunks is not None, chunk_index is not None, unique_upload_id, orig_file_name)):
        print((total_chunks, chunk_index, unique_upload_id, orig_file_name))
        return jsonify({'msg': 'Missing headers'}), 400 
    
    # create new and secure file_name
    orig_file_name = Path(orig_file_name)
    tmp_filename = secure_filename(f"{unique_upload_id}_{orig_file_name.name}")
    upload_folder = Path("/", "tmp", "upload")
    file_path = upload_folder / tmp_filename

    upload_folder.mkdir(mode=660, parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    chunk = request.stream.read()
    
    # todo: cleanup after dev
    file_lock = open(file_path, 'a')
    lock_count = 0
    try:
        while lock_count <= 5:
            lock_count += 1
            try:
                fcntl.flock(file_lock.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
                break
            except Exception:
                print("File is locked!")
                sleep(0.1)
        with open(file_path, 'ab') as temp_file:
            temp_file.seek(chunk_index * 10 * 1024 * 1024)  # 10 MB
            print(f"Chunk: {chunk_index+1}/{total_chunks} \t len: {len(chunk)} \t FPos: {temp_file.tell()}")
            temp_file.write(chunk)
            temp_file.flush()
            os.fsync(temp_file.fileno())
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"stderr: {e.strerror}")
        return jsonify({'msg': e.strerror}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return jsonify({'msg': 'Something went wrong while writing the file.'}), 500
    finally:
        # Unlock the file
        fcntl.flock(file_lock.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        file_lock.close()

    return jsonify({'msg': 'File chunk saved'}), 200
```

Thank you in advance.